# UnicodeDecodeError Python 3.5.1 Email Script

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to send an email + attachment to an SMS gateway email.  However I currently am getting a Unicode Decode: Error'Charmap' codec can't Decode Byte 0x8d in position 60

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this and would be interested in your advice.  Bellow is my code and the Full Error.

```
import smtplib, os

from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart


msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Cuteness'
msg['From'] = 'sample@outlook.com'
msg['To'] = '111111111@messaging.sprintpcs.com'
msg.preamble = "Would you pet me?   I'd Pet me so hard..."

here = os.getcwd() 
file = open('cutecat.png')#the png shares directory with actual script

for here in file:  #Error appears to be in this section
    with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
        img = MIMImage(fp.read())
    msg.attach(img)


s = smtplib.SMTP('Localhost')
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()

""" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\Test_Box\msgr.py", line 16, in <module>
    for here in file:
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 60: character maps to <undefined>"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to open the file twice. First you have:

```
file = open('cutecat.png')
```

The default mode to open files is to read them in text mode. That is generally not what you want to do with a binary file like a PNG file.

And then you do:

```
for here in file:
    with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
        img = MIMImage(fp.read())
    msg.attach(img)
```

You get an exception in the first line because Python is trying to decode the contents of a binary file as text and fails. The chances of this happening are quite high. It is unlikely that a binary file is also a valid text file in your standard encoding.

But even if that would have worked, for every line in the file you try to open the file again? This makes no sense!

Were you just copy/pasting from the [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email-examples.html), especially the third one? You should note that this example is *incomplete*. The variable `pngfiles` used in that example (and which *should* be a sequence of file names) is not defined.

Try this instead:

```
with open('cutecat.png', 'rb') as fp:
    img = MIMImage(fp.read())
msg.attach(img)
```

Or if you want to include multiple files:

```
pngfiles = ('cutecat.png', 'kitten.png')
for filename in pngfiles:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
        img = MIMImage(fp.read())
    msg.attach(img)
```

Comment: Opps!  Yes I forgot I left that in there I was trouble shooting earlier and had forgotten to fix that.  At this point in the day I had been working on another project for 8 hours and was starting to get lazy.